# How to subtract db values using php

Tags: php, variables, mysqli, subtraction

How exactly do I subtract values from a database using php? I see plenty of examples using static variables such as

```
<?php
$first_number = 10;
$second_number = 2;
$third_number = 3;
$sum_total = $third_number + $second_number * $first_number;
print ($sum_total);
?>
```

However I'm looking to subtract one database value from another, then multiply that value by another db value. To give some more detail, I have an inventory database where I'm echoing the values into a table, I'm attempting to subtract the total quantity of an item from the minimum quantity, to see how many need to be ordered, then multiply the number of parts we need to order by the cost of that part. I've dug around and found a few possible methods such as

```
$query = "SELECT `db`, 
         (`minimumquantity` - `totalquantity`) AS `quantitytoorder`
        FROM `db` 
        WHERE id ='".$id."';"
```

and

```
<?php
$minimumquantity = $_GET['minimumquantity'];
$totalquantity = $_GET['totalquantity'];

$quantitytoorder = $minimumquantity - $totalquantity;
print ($quantitytoorder);
?>
```

Please before you laugh, I'm very much a beginner, can anyone point me in the right direction, or provide me with proper examples? My only real resource is the net and most examples I find are very high-level.

```
Field             Type        Null     Key   Default  Extra   
id                int(3)      NO       PRI   NULL     auto_increment 
partnumber        varchar(20) NO             NULL  
description       varchar(20) NO             NULL  
tonerprice        int(20)     NO             NULL  
totalquantity     int(20)     NO             NULL  
minimumquantity   int(20)     NO             NULL  
quantitytoorder   int(20)     NO             NULL  
replencost        int(20)     NO             NULL
```

Comment: Have you tried any of that? That SQL example looks decent. Do you know how to fetch data from the database using PHP and simply outputting it?

Comment: Why was this close-voted? It's a perfectly valid question, and it includes code, and the OP has made some research efforts, too.

Comment: Are all the values you need to analyse already in the database?  If so paste here your db schema's table (layout) using the SQL statement "DESCRIBE table_name_here" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/describe.html

Comment: //Do you know how to fetch data from the database using PHP and simply outputting it// I have an inventory database where I'm echoing the values into a table, I don't have any issue displaying the values, I'm having trouble with mathematical operations via php, I have an excel sheet that does this just fine, but I want to move it all online

Comment: This question hardly makes sense. As you've already found out, both PHP and SQL use the same operator for substraction (`-`) with the same syntax (a - b), which is exactly the syntax you were taught at primary school. I have a strong feeling that you haven't explained what your actual problem is.

Comment: I don't understand who upvoted this. Being very much a beginner, the OP have to explain the **root** problem, not come up with some strange XY problem without any explanation

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the values held in the columns of your table or just perform some mathematical operations on the data before you present values to the user?

Comment: I suppose the root problem is my lack of knowledge, I have a degree in networking, not programming, I definitely appreciate the more helpful users in this community, I disagree with your statement that my question is some strange XY problem, seems extremely straight-forward to me. Yes I'm just looking to display the values, all the user input takes place elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming you know how to work with SQL in PHP, it's as simple as this:

```
// STOP USING mysql, use mysqli or PDO, for demonstration purposes only
$results = mysql_query('SELECT foo, bar, baz FROM table');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    echo $row['foo'] - $row['bar'] * $row['baz'];
}
```

Assuming the columns are all numeric, that's all you need to do to subtract and multiply values from the database in PHP.

Comment: Ok so when I subtract my total quantity from the minimum quantity, to get the number of parts I need to order, do I have to pass that to the db before I can take that value and multiply it by the cost?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You can do that anywhere. You can do subtractions in SQL, as in the example you show in your question. MySQL will then do the math as part of the query and return you some calculated value. Or you get all the values from the database and do calculations in PHP, as shown in my answer. Both PHP and MySQL happen to be able to do math very easily. Where to do it depends on your circumstances. If all the values you need for the calculation are inside the database, it makes sense to let SQL do it and just return you the values. Otherwise do it in PHP.

Comment: My mistake your example already answered, my question, however I'm getting a negative number, thank you for your assistance!! I just had to add () around my subtraction

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will need to look into using mysql within php. Php has a built in class specifically created to do this. Documentation, examples and everything else a beginner needs is available [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Secondly the query you are trying to do is possible and you are on the right tracks, try something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT (minimumquantity - totalquantity) AS quantitytoorder, (quantitytoorder * costofpart) AS totalcost FROM db WHERE id = '".$id."';";
```

My advice is to read through the mysqli documentation and do some simple examples first to get familiar with it - then you should try and complete your own task.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

> SELECT (value2-value1) as minimumquantity,((value1 + value2)* value3)
>   as totalquantity FROM `table` WHERE id = '".$id."';";